# Runtime error running non-storyboard app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I am writing an iOS app; no ARC and no storyboards.
I have a view controller inside Navigation controller. It supposed to have  Table view and navigation button which pushes to second view.
 This is the error I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8d012 0x10cae7e 0x1c8cdeb 0xf2f18 0xf3418 0xf3648 0xf3882 0x42a25 0x42dbf 0x42f55 0x4bf67 0x2a88 0xf7b7 0xfda7 0x10fab 0x22315 0x2324b 0x14cf8 0x1be8df9 0x1be8ad0 0x1c02bf5 0x1c02962 0x1c33bb6 0x1c32f44 0x1c32e1b 0x107da 0x1265c 0x2442 0x2375)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

The code in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    self.viewCon = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewCon];
    self.navCon.navigationBar.tintColor= [UIColor greenColor];
    self.viewCon.title= @"First View";

    self.tblView = [[UITableView alloc] init];


    NSMutableArray *viewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewArr addObject:self.navCon];

    self.navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

    self.viewCon.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second View"  style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:(nil)];


    [self.window addSubview:self.navBar];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewCon;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

At this stage I cannot run even the app. What might be the prob? 
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.

It seems you forgot to connect the `view` outlet of the view controller to your actual view in ViewController.xib file.

Your xib file has got a file's owner. This you have presumably set to be a `ViewController` (which I imagine is a subclass of `UIViewController`).
Now, if you go to the right-hand pane and show the bindings pane (the last one, with a small arrow), you will see that the view controller has got an outlet called `view`: drag from the small circle on its right on to the view which you have created in the xib.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that. In the View Controller setting it has been set NIB Name to ViewController and Title to First View. Do you mean here something else?

Comment: At the beginning that view once View Controller on Objects pane has been selected pointed to 'table view. My View Controller is inside Navigation Controller. And View Controller has a table view. So I deleted table view. Now I cannot connect to my View Controller in the way you say.

Comment: I am not sure I understand... maybe you should have not deleted the table view. or, if you like, try to create a new empty view and connect it like I said in my answer and see if it works.